# I'm trying to use jQuery to disable form inputs. It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: jquery, disabled-input

I would like to disable all the inputs in my form by default, and only enable them if the user checks off a "Terms and Conditions" checkbox.

The problem is that it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Sometimes it fails to disable by default, but toggling the checkbox works. Other times I can't get the inputs to disable at all.

The form itself is a 3rd party JS widget loaded in the body of the document, and I have this script getting called in the header:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// by default, disable all the form inputs

$( "form :input" ).prop( "disabled", true );

$( "#terms-checkbox" ).change( function() {

    // if the Terms and Conditions checkbox is checked, enable the form inputs

    if ( this.checked ) {
        $( "form :input" ).prop( "disabled", false );
    } else {
        $( "form :input" ).prop( "disabled", true );
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Your JS is working fine for me. **[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/wm0ydLc3/)** You should make sure that the form is loaded before the DOM ready event is fired.

Comment: The form is loading from an external website. It's getting called in the body of the document. How can I make sure that it's loaded before the ready event is fired?

Comment: Need to see the code that causes the 3rd party form widget to load.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Aust, your code works just fine. However, you can reduce:

```
if ( this.checked ) {
    $( "form :input" ).prop( "disabled", false );
} else {
    $( "form :input" ).prop( "disabled", true );
}
```

To:

```
$( "form :input" ).prop( "disabled", !this.checked );
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was actually CloudFlare's Rocket Loader feature that was messing it up. I fixed the problematic script with this: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436-How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-

Thank you so much for your help guys!